# What year did Isaac Newton die?

Tags: 18th-century, mathematics, isaac-newton

What is the year of death of Isaac Newton? Different sources provide info that it's either 1726 or 1727.

On his tomb is written 1726, [findagrave.com](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/1277/isaac-newton) has it listed as 1727, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton) even states:

> "20 March 1726/1727"

but later on that page

> "20 March 1727 (OS 20 March 1726; NS 31 March 1727)"

This seems to me not to be a Julian Calendar vs Gregorian Calendar issue: based on my experience, differences between the Julian Calendar and the Gregorian Calendar dates are between the number of 11–13 days, not 365 days?

Comment: Both sites you link to give the same date (in the current Gregorian calendar). The other date mentioned in Wikipedia is the "old style" (Julian calendar) date.

Comment: Specifically, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton has footnote a explaining this Old Style dating problem, which you flatly deny? If you doubt that narrative from WP, it is up to you to explain _why_ "this is not a Julian Calendar vs Gregorian Calendar issue"?

Comment: Based on my experience, difference between the Julian Calendar and the Gregorian Calendar is in number of 11-13 days, not 365 days.

Comment: Issac -> Isaac.

Comment: @JaneB. As the note on the Wikipedia page says, "_he died in the period after the start of the New Style year on 1 January, but before that of the Old Style new year on 25 March. His death occurred on 20 March 1726 according to the Old Style calendar, but the year is usually adjusted to 1727. A full conversion to New Style gives the date 31 March 1727_"

Comment: @LаngLаngС,SteveBird:  So technically it's correct that this isn't due to a confusion between the Julian & Gregorian calendars.  The issue is that the change from "New Style" to "Old Style" in England also involved redefining which day started the year.

Comment: I don't think this was off-topic here, but I'm pretty sure History of Science and Math (http://hsm.stackexchange.com) would have loved to field this one.

Comment: Also 1927 -> 1727.

Comment: This question is not an off topic. It presents an interesting problem of not only a change from the Julian Calendar to the Gregorian one, but also the change of the beginning of the year in England in the 18th century.

Comment: I believe that we should leave open questions with an answer, particularly an accepted answer.

Comment: @MCW That is one argument to make, but it also clearly clashes with a few other quality assessment criteria for question closure, most importantly: off-topic for rather clearly 'too-basic'? It _is answered_ with several equally good & exhaustive _'single links'_… // Now, the banner does nowhere say 'it should stay closed forever'. That is: if JaneB. or at least her/the Qtext demonstrates prior research & a responsive [edit] addressing the apparent complaints from comments—then I will most probably also vote to re-open it.

Comment: True and agreed.  Which principle should take precedence?  For me - personal opinion, "too basic" is intended to avoid wasting people's time.  But once someone has chosen to invest that time (and particularly if OP indicates that the research was worthwhile), then "too basic" no longer applies.  Contrary arguments can be made, but IMHO, the goal is to educate & illuminate and that is best served by not closing questions with acceptable answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When Newton died, the British started the new year on March 25 (Lady Day). In 1752, the UK switched to starting the New Year on January 1.  Dates between January 1 and March 25 prior to 1752 happened in different years Old Style vs. New Style.

This is all explained nicely at: [Wikipedia: Old Style and New Style dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Style_and_New_Style_dates)

Added (thanks to @LangLangC for the excellent link): [Calendrical confusion or just when did Newton die?](https://thonyc.wordpress.com/2015/03/20/calendrical-confusion-or-just-when-did-newton-die/)

Comment: Please add also his own WP page's footnote that leads to this very specific page: [Calendrical confusion or just when did Newton die?](https://thonyc.wordpress.com/2015/03/20/calendrical-confusion-or-just-when-did-newton-die/)